# gradlew failed with return code: 1 in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an android code that build successfully on android studio but when build in Azure DevOps Pipeline it get the following error, what could be the problem?

> BUILD FAILED in 2m 8s 55 actionable tasks: 55 executed Error:
>   /home/vsts/work/1/s/gradlew failed with return code: 1
>       at ChildProcess. (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.149.1/node_modules/vsts-task-lib/toolrunner.js:639:25)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5) No test result files matching
>   /home/vsts/work/1/s/**/TEST-*.xml were found, so publishing JUnit test
>   results is being skipped.
>   [error]Error: /home/vsts/work/1/s/gradlew failed with return code: 1

Comment: I am facing same issue working fine in Android studio but Azura pipeline getting same Error.

Comment: is it possible that the results file is being produced, but saved in a different location? If you disable the automatic reporting of results from your test task, you can use an ad hoc script to investigate where the results file actually is.